# Problema con if en javascript c/ p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo este código que he ido modificando a partir de unos videos de "The Coding Train", y quiero detectar el momento en el que una variable llamada `current` es igual a `grid.length` (o a `cols*rows`, ya que sería lo mismo).
Os dejo abajo el código ya que he intentado de mil maneras distintas detectarlo pero lo consigo.

PD: Necesito ese `if` en la función `draw()`. No pongo el `if` que he probado ya que he probado muchos, como de 20 maneras distintas...

```js
  //Variables//
  
  var w = 50;
  if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {var max = w * Math.floor(window.innerWidth/w)} else {var max = w * Math.floor(window.innerHeight/w)}
  var cols;
  var rows;
  var grid = [];
  var stack = [];
  var current = 0;
  
  //Funciones//
  
  function setup() {
   if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {max = w * Math.floor(window.innerWidth/w)} else {max = w * Math.floor(window.innerHeight/w)}
   createCanvas(max, max);
   cols = Math.floor(width/w);
   rows = Math.floor(height/w);
   //frameRate(7:-);
   
   for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
     var cell = new Cell(i, j);
     grid.push(cell);
    }
   }
  }

  function draw() {
   background(51);
   for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].show();
   }
   
   grid[current].visited = true;
   if (current == grid.length || current == cols * rows) {console.log("asd")};
   var next = grid[current].checkNeighbors();
   if (next) {
    stack.push(current);
    removeWalls(grid[current], grid[next]);
    next.visited = true;
    current = next;
   } else if (stack.length > 0){
    while (grid[current].checkNeighbors() == undefined) {
     if (stack.length === 0) {break};
     current = stack.pop();
    }
   }
   
   push();
    noFill();
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    strokeWeight(20);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);
   pop();
  }
  
  function index(i, j) {
   if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols - 1 || j > rows - 1) {
    return false;
   }
  
   return i + j * cols;
  }
  
  function removeWalls(a, b) {
   var x = a.i - b.i;
   if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false
   } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
   }
   
   var y = a.j - b.j;
   if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false
   } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
   }
  }
  
    
    
    
    
    //Cell
  class Cell {
   constructor(i, j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
    this.visited = false;
   }
   
   show() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    stroke(255);
    
    if (this.walls[0]) {
     line(x    , y    , x + w, y    );
    };
    if (this.walls[1]) {
     line(x + w, y    , x + w, y + w);
    };
    if (this.walls[2]) {
     line(x + w, y + w, x    , y + w);
    };
    if (this.walls[3]) {
     line(x    , y + w, x    , y    );
    };
    
    if (this.visited) {
     fill(255, 0, 255, 100);
     noStroke();
     rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
   }
   
   checkNeighbors() {
    var neighbors = [];
    
    var top    = index(this.i    , this.j - 1);
    var right  = index(this.i + 1, this.j    );
    var bottom = index(this.i    , this.j + 1);
    var left   = index(this.i - 1, this.j    );
   
    if (top && !grid[top].visited) {
     neighbors.push(top);
    }
    if (right && !grid[right].visited) {
     neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if (bottom && !grid[bottom].visited) {
     neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if (left && !grid[left].visited) {
     neighbors.push(left);
    }
    
    if (neighbors.length > 0) {
     var r = Math.floor(random(0, neighbors.length));
     return neighbors[r];
    } else {
     return undefined;
    }
   }
  }
```

```css
  * {
   margin: 0px;
   border: 0px;
   padding:0px;
  };
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script></script>
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO

Si en vez de comprobar algo relativo como si `current` es igual a algo, es más sencillo, en este caso, comprobar si está `visited` añadiendo una variable (`contador` en este caso) de modo que el código quedaría así:

```js
  //Variables//
  
  var w = 50;
  if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {var max = w * Math.floor(window.innerWidth/w)} else {var max = w * Math.floor(window.innerHeight/w)}
  var cols;
  var rows;
  var grid = [];
  var stack = [];
  var current = 0;
  var contador = true;
  
  //Funciones//
  
  function setup() {
   if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {max = w * Math.floor(window.innerWidth/w)} else {max = w * Math.floor(window.innerHeight/w)}
   createCanvas(max, max);
   cols = Math.floor(width/w);
   rows = Math.floor(height/w);
   //frameRate(7:-);
   
   for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
     var cell = new Cell(i, j);
     grid.push(cell);
    }
   }
  }

  function draw() {
   background(51);
   for (var i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    grid[i].show();
   }
   
   grid[current].visited = true;
   if (grid[grid.length - 1].visited && contador) {console.log("Ya"); contador = false;};
   var next = grid[current].checkNeighbors();
   if (next) {
    stack.push(current);
    removeWalls(grid[current], grid[next]);
    next.visited = true;
    current = next;
   } else if (stack.length > 0){
    while (grid[current].checkNeighbors() == undefined) {
     if (stack.length === 0) {break};
     current = stack.pop();
    }
   }
   
   push();
    noFill();
    stroke(0, 255, 0);
    strokeWeight(20);
    rect(0, 0, width, height);
   pop();
  }
  
  function index(i, j) {
   if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > cols - 1 || j > rows - 1) {
    return false;
   }
  
   return i + j * cols;
  }
  
  function removeWalls(a, b) {
   var x = a.i - b.i;
   if (x === 1) {
    a.walls[3] = false;
    b.walls[1] = false
   } else if (x === -1) {
    a.walls[1] = false;
    b.walls[3] = false;
   }
   
   var y = a.j - b.j;
   if (y === 1) {
    a.walls[0] = false;
    b.walls[2] = false
   } else if (y === -1) {
    a.walls[2] = false;
    b.walls[0] = false;
   }
  }
  
  class Cell {
   constructor(i, j) {
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    this.walls = [true, true, true, true];
    this.visited = false;
   }
   
   show() {
    var x = this.i * w;
    var y = this.j * w;
    stroke(255);
    
    if (this.walls[0]) {
     line(x    , y    , x + w, y    );
    };
    if (this.walls[1]) {
     line(x + w, y    , x + w, y + w);
    };
    if (this.walls[2]) {
     line(x + w, y + w, x    , y + w);
    };
    if (this.walls[3]) {
     line(x    , y + w, x    , y    );
    };
    
    if (this.visited) {
     fill(255, 0, 255, 100);
     noStroke();
     rect(x, y, w, w);
    }
   }
   
   checkNeighbors() {
    var neighbors = [];
    
    var top    = index(this.i    , this.j - 1);
    var right  = index(this.i + 1, this.j    );
    var bottom = index(this.i    , this.j + 1);
    var left   = index(this.i - 1, this.j    );
   
    if (top && !grid[top].visited) {
     neighbors.push(top);
    }
    if (right && !grid[right].visited) {
     neighbors.push(right);
    }
    if (bottom && !grid[bottom].visited) {
     neighbors.push(bottom);
    }
    if (left && !grid[left].visited) {
     neighbors.push(left);
    }
    
    if (neighbors.length > 0) {
     var r = Math.floor(random(0, neighbors.length));
     return neighbors[r];
    } else {
     return undefined;
    }
   }
  }
```

```css
  * {
   margin: 0px;
   border: 0px;
   padding:0px;
  };
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/p5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.1/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script></script>
  </head>
  <body style="text-align:center">
  </body>
</html>
```